# How many workouts should I do per gym workout session?

Tags: workout-routines, gym, muscle-gain

I am new to fitness and want to get on the right foot from some of you experience goers. I am very flexible to trying any great ideas and I am very open minded.My goal is to bulk up and gain muscle and so far my friends help me with a diet that works for me. But I want to know specifically more on the gym side. I have a workout schedule I want to start doing but before doing that, I want to know how many exercises should I be doing per day/1 workout session. For example, if I do chest and triceps day, how many workouts should I be doing this day ? The reason I ask is because I want to ensure I do not over train and exhaust myself but also I do not want to under train. Please keep in mind my only time slot at the gym is 1 hour - 1 hour 15 min. Below are my details, let me know your thoughts ! I am very exited to start this week and improve by learning.

Details:

- Height : 5 ft 9in
- Weight : 155 lbs
- Goal Weight : 165+ lbs
- Work From home, so I cook

Plan for the gym:

- Attend 5:00 AM since I work most of the day
- Mon - Rest
- Tues - Core
- Wed - Shoulders
- Thurs - Chest + Triceps
- Fri - Rest
- Sat - Legs
- Sun - Back and Biceps

Diet:

- Eat Breakfast at 7:00 AM, Lunch at 3:00 PM, Dinner at 7:00 PM
- I measure to ensure I eat the same proportion everytime

Breakfast:

- 780 Cals, 60g protein, 52g Carbs

Lunch:

- 1100 Cals, 45g protein, 43g Carbs

Dinner:

- 665 Cals, 30g protein, 21g Carbs

Comment: I assume you meant how many exercises per session? As a beginner I wouldn't worry so much about overtraining yet. Also I believe you can find plenty of online program samples that fit your training split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all congrats on taking the leap and start going to the gym !

From what I could read on the internet, recomended number of set for major muscle groupe vary between 10 to 30 sets/muscle group per week, depending on your level of weightlifting and the said sources (As always in the fitness topic, there are a lot of different sources that says a lot of different things).

From my experience, I have almost the same time allocated to go to the gym, and I can insure you that if you take a decent amount of rest between your sets, you won't really have the time to overtrain.

I also think that one good thing is that, as a beginner, you don't need a massive number of sets to have good gains so you can test and see how well you manage fatigue from one workout to an other, increasing or decreasing as needed.

Also as pointed by Luciano, there are a lot of available programs on the net that might suit your needs, most of them take that kind of things into account.

Sorry if the answer is a bit opinion based and not very sourced, but at least maybe it can help !

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I will take your advice and work hard !